# Datetime not saved properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker

I have a model Terms which has these columns :name, :start_date and :end_date.

I fill the start_date and end_date fields with the jQuery datetimepicker.

Using better errors I checked the term_params and seemed fine:

```
>> term_params
=> {"name"=>"Test", "start_date"=>"09/29/2015 10:51 AM", "end_date"=>"10/08/2015 10:51 AM"}
```

and then I saved the object to make sure it saves fine:

```
>> @term.save!
=> true
```

Then I checked the object and saw that the start_date is nil:

```
>> @term
=> #<Term id: 8, name: "Test", start_date: nil, end_date: "2015-08-10 10:51:00", created_at: "2015-09-09 07:51:59", updated_at: "2015-09-09 07:51:59">
```

I searched the logs for un-permitted start_date just in case and couldn't find any.

On the server the logs recorded these:

```
Started POST "/terms" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-09-09 10:51:27 +0300
Processing by TermsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"uHh88e875EFNI2Iktfiidm5qzgeOop997b+gIrjtSEp1g/cqK1KYBJWhNJhCwo67bojGeJiTD8R/ngs8kmcWsQ==", "term"=>{"name"=>"Test", "start_date"=>"09/29/2015 10:51 AM", "end_date"=>"10/08/2015 10:51 AM"}, "commit"=>"Create Term"}
  Admin Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "terms" ("name", "end_date", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Test"], ["end_date", "2015-08-10  00:00:00.000000"], ["created_at", "2015-09-09 07:51:27.632512"], ["updated_at", "2015-09-09 07:51:27.632512"]]
   (2.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://127.0.0.1:3000/terms
Completed 302 Found in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
```

I don't understand why is stat_date missing from the INSERT INTO when it was send in the parameters list. The funny thing is that when I try again and again sometimes it doesn't record both start_date and end_date or even on one occasion it record both fine.

Any clue what might be wrong?

Just in case you might want to see the code behind it (terms_controller.rb):

```
  def create
      @term = Term.new(term_params)

      if @term.save
        flash.notice = "Term was created successfully!"
        redirect_to terms_path
      else
        flash.warning = "Something went wrong. Please try again!"
        render 'new'
      end
  end
```

and

```
  private
    def term_params
      params.require(:term).permit(:name, :start_date, :end_date)
    end
```

Comment: What is the `datatype` of `start_date`?

Comment: Whats the format? `mm/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: @Pavan, yes. it is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: When you look into `INSERT INTO` query the value of `end_date` is changed to **2015-08-10(yyyy-mm-dd)** format, so when it comes to `start_date`, the value would be **2015-29-09(yyyy-mm-dd)** where **29** is not a valid month, so Rails is failing to save that value. May be you need to change the format to `dd/mm/yyyy` and try.

Comment: @Pavan yes. that was the issue. Thank you. I would never thought of that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies with ***format***. When you look into `INSERT INTO` query the value of `end_date` is changed to ***2015-08-10(yyyy-mm-dd)*** format, so when it comes to `start_date`, the value would be ***2015-29-09(yyyy-mm-dd)*** where ***29*** is not a valid month, so Rails is failing to save that value. May be you need to change the format to ***dd/mm/yyyy*** and try.